# Chromium calculates table width incorrectly?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, chromium

So I have a wide table which is displayed a bit wrong in last versions of Chromium. Version 37 renders it correctly, 44 does not.

The problem is that the last column is not included in the table/thead/tbody width. So the caption is narrower than it should be. If I set `table-layout:fixed` this bug disappears, but I have to use `auto`.

Looks like a chromium bug, but anyways, is there a workaround for this?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lk8coxL6/) of the below:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption style="background: lightgreen;">
    Caption
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Title
      </th>
      <th>
        Description
      </th>
      <th>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </th>
      <th>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </th>
      <th>
        Actions
      </th>
      <th>
        Actions
      </th>
      <th>
        Actions
      </th>
      <th>
        Actions
      </th>
      <th>

      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                        adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dignissim mauris vel auctor
                        dapibus. Morbi scelerisque interdum magna, sed pulvinar
                        libero fringilla quis. Vivamus maximus lorem tempor
                        nibh eleifend, ac euismod velit dictum.</span>
      </td>
      <td>qwe</td>
      <td>qwe</td>
      <td>qwe</td>
      <td>qwe</td>
      <td>qwe</td>
      <td>qwe</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like if we don't see the code, we can't see the problem. We aren't wizards or witches.

Comment: Oops, added jsfiddle.

Comment: What you explained is different case than the fiddle, can you please put the right code and show us the problem based on the fiddle

Comment: Oooo, this is fascinating (in Chrome) - [look at what happens when you remove the border collapse and give the table a big border... the cells are overflowing the table...](https://jsfiddle.net/aftskx68/)

Comment: @misterManSam yes, this is exactly what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is a fascinating Chrome bug.

Here is a workaround [using `<col>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) to give the description column a `width: 100%` (substitute the width size as desired) This stops the bug and doesn't break any column widths:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 10px #F00
}
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
.description {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption style="background: lightgreen;">Caption</caption>
  <col>
  <col class="description">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>1Title</th>
            <th>2Description</th>
            <th>3Lorem Ipsum</th>
            <th>4 Lorem Ipsum</th>
            <th>5 Actions</th>
            <th>6 Actions</th>
            <th>7 Actions</th>
            <th>8 Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
            <td>2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dignissim mauris vel auctor dapibus. Morbi scelerisque interdum magna, sed pulvinar libero fringilla quis. Vivamus maximus lorem tempor nibh eleifend, ac euismod velit dictum.

            </td>
            <td>3qwe</td>
            <td>4qwe</td>
            <td>5qwe</td>
            <td>6qwe</td>
            <td>7qwe</td>
            <td>8qwe</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved me a ton of time!

Comment: @ValeriyStreltsov - no worries :) If the `width: 100%` causes any other issues, you can just change it to something smaller and it shouldn't have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a problem of number of  and  because there are one more  in first row than  in second row. The TH is empty and the TD doesn't exists. Please, test this:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lk8coxL6/2/

I've add an space in empty th and I add the missing td.

```
<th> &nbsp; </th>
```

And

```
<td> qwe </td>
```

Good luck

Comment: Didn't solve the issue. I added one more screenshot.

Comment: It is no reason to downvote. The next time, will help you your cousin.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry for my comment

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude -- this answer doesn't solve the problem presented in the question or explain the bug that is present here. Usually, when presenting some options to try, it is better to leave them as a comment, especially if you are unsure :)